# Webpack - How to reuse global library name when it already exists?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, webpack-4, monorepo

Good evening!

I have this monorepo with multiple packages, where each of them is bundled independently using Webpack.

Before it was a monorepo, I would have a single bundle file, and it would be possible to have it available through a global variable within the browser through `output.library` property. Now I have the following since I have multiple entries:

```
output: {
    library: "SC",
    // export itself to UMD format
    libraryTarget: "umd",
    umdNamedDefine: true,
    filename: "[name]/dist/organization-[name].js",
    // fix for https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6525
    globalObject: `(typeof self !== 'undefined' ? self : this)`
  }
```

The problem is that if I use this same config for every package, and I import more than one to the **browser** using **script** tags, only the latest script will actually be available because it's essentially recreating the global variable each time.

Is there a way to reuse it? Or maybe a better convention I could use here.
In node, for instance, I import each of them using the bundle name, but in the browser, I feel like it should all be under the same global variable.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: Because you're bundling your scripts individually, the variables defined in one scope can't talk to the other scripts. The only way I can think of is to assign output to the window object. This feels dirty though.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. That's why I'm trying to find a good way to reuse the scope when it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the issue I created over webpack's [repository](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8898), the solution is to use the following:
`library: ["MyLibrary", "[name]"]`

That will make all packages available under the same global variable `MyLibrary` but separated by their respective entry (i.e., `MyLibrary.entryOne` and `MyLibrary.entryTwo`).